# Programatically send an email from an elisp function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to automatically send an email from within an elisp function.  Hypothetically, I would like a single function which I can pass in the to, from, subject, body, and possibly other headers.  Does such a function exist?  If not how could it be implemented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This snippet will send a mail in Emacs:

```
(progn
    (mail) 
    (mail-to) (insert "recipient@nomail.invalid")
    (mail-subject) (insert "the subject")
    (mail-text) (insert "body of mail")
    (mail-send))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What versions of emacs does this apply to? In GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on Windows, I can't find the documentation for any of those functions except for 'mail'. And mail seems to take arguments for 'to', 'subject', etc. Has this changed in recent versions of Emacs?

Comment: Here (in what will be emacs 25) `mail` is an autoloaded command, i.ow. using it will load sendmail.el, which defines `mail-to`, `mail-subject`, etc. So once you used `mail`, the others should be defined. Alternatively, do `M-x load-library RET sendmail RET`